# Trying to decrypt and print out a text file I encrypted in same program

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, encryption, key-value

So I finally figured out how to read and encrypt a text file. Now I have to create a second program that opens the encrypted file then display its decrypted contents on the screen. I was good until I had to reverse and figure out how print out the key in the dictionary. Any help is great, TIA!

here is my code:

```
    dictionary = {'A':'D', 'B':'E', 'C':'F', 'D':'G', 'E':'H', 
            'F':'I', 'G':'J', 'H':'K','I':'L',\
            'J':'M', 'K':'N', 'L':'O', 'M':'P', 'N':'Q', 'O':'R', 
            'P':'S', 'Q':'T', 'R':'U',\
            'V':'Y', 'W':'Z', 'X':'A', 'Y':'B', 'Z':'C'}
    def encrypt_file():
        file = open('texttoencrypt.txt', 'r')
        new_file = open('encrypted_text.txt', 'w')

        while True:
            char = file.read(1)
             if not char:
                break
            char = char.upper()
            if char in dictionary.keys():
                 new_char = dictionary[char]
                 new_file.write(new_char)
            else:
                 new_file.write(char)

         file.close()
         new_file.close()

    encrypt_file()

    def decrypt_file():
        encrypted = open('encrypted_text.txt', 'r')
        decrypt = ''
        while True:
            char = encrypted.read(1)
            if not char:
                break
            for key, values in dictionary.items():
                 if char in values:
                     decrypt+= key
                 else:
                     decrypt += char
         print(decrypt)
         encrypted.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a dictionary can be done using list comprehension, like this:
`reversed_dictionary = {(v,k) for k,v in dictionary.items()}`. This assumes you have no duplicate values in the original, which yours shouldn't have in the first place. Not sure what you mean by ' print out the key in the dictionary', though.

Note that you'll probably be better off using an already exiting solution, which would be the 'translate' method. Here is an example of this, which also discovers a issue with your translation table:

```
plain =     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRVWXYZ'
scrambled = 'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUYZABC'

scramble = str.maketrans(plain, scrambled)
descramble = str.maketrans(scrambled, plain)

s1 = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG"
s2 = s1.translate(scramble)
s3 = s2.translate(descramble)

print("Original:    %s" % s1)
print("Scrambled:   %s" % s2)
print("Descrambled: %s" % s3)
```

Comment: How do I do a user mention in a response? I tried @ and # and then run out of ideas...

Comment: @LydiavanDyke - you type @ and then a first letter of the user, and it lets you tag one.

Comment: hm. in the comment section I also see a text block saying the same thing. but @Boris it does not work currently.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your currently used dictionary is *not* invertible. Because letters 'S', 'T' and 'U' are not present, they will be implicitly mapped onto them self. So 'S' is implicitly mapped to 'S'. However, 'P' is also mapped to 'S' by your dictionary.

If this issue is fixed, the key point to reversing your encryption is of course the dictionary-reversing as pointed out by @Boris Lipschitz.

However, your code does not easily support this. Why? Because your encrypt_file method does way to much. It opens a file, it encrypts and it saves a file. Too much! A method should do *one* thing only. Consider this approach:

```py
def encrypt(content, mapping):
    result = ""
    for char in content:
        char = char.upper()
        if char in mapping.keys():
            new_char = mapping[char]
            result += new_char
        else:
            result += char
    return result


with open('texttoencrypt.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(content)
    encrypted = encrypt(content, dictionary)

print(encrypted)

reversed_mapping = {v: k for k, v in dictionary.items()}
decrypted = encrypt(encrypted, reversed_mapping)

print(decrypted)
```

This is almost exactly your code, but I moved everything that is not related to the encryption algorithm out of the encrypt method. Now it can be easily reused to decrypt! (You could further improve this by just writing `result += mapping.get(char, char)` but I wanted to stay close to your original code.

Boris Lipschitz' argument is perfectly valid, however: Do not reinvent the wheel. Just use the maketrans/transform solution :)

Comment: While i totally agree on separating it into a function, something one got to learn in addition to proper coding is to not reinvent the wheel. The `translate` method does almost exactly what's being required here, and, IMO, should be used instead.

Comment: That depends. In case it is 'production code' in any way you clearly are right! In case this is for a homework of some kind, just solving the task with 'import caesar_cipher' might be a little underwhelming :)

Comment: Kinda makes me wonder if the next exercise is gonna be 'write a code to try and crack substitution ciphers assuming the message is in English', lol. And yea, i agree.

Comment: Both of these are SO helpful!! Thank you both. When I started the program my first intentions were to just read, encrypt, and save to a second file and I had no specific methods.  When I brought in the methods, I kind of threw them in not knowing where to start. I will do some revisions with your advice and examples and see what I can do. Thank you!

Comment: `''.join(chr((ord(c)-ord('A')+shift)%26+ord('A')) if c>='A' and c<='Z' else c for c in str)` this will actually do caesar for you in one line, without substitution table, set str to your sting, shift to 3 for scramble, 23 for descramble ;-) (disclaimer: trying to emulate Python gurus here, i don't usually code like this, lol)